# Есть ли в Python тернарный условный оператор?

Tags: python, if, операторы

Есть ли в Python тернарный оператор?

*Примечание. Это перевод замечательного вопроса с enSO [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)*

Comment: зачем делать такие переводы?

Comment: @sad, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, он был добавлен в версии 2.5. Вот его синтаксис:

```
a if condition else b
```

Сначала вычисляется `condition`, затем, в соответствии с его булевым значением, вычисляется и возвращается `a` или `b`. Если `condition` равно True, вычисляется и возвращается `a`, а `b` игнорируется; в противном случае вычисляется и возвращается `b`, а `a` игнорируется.

Это позволяет провести так называемое *сокращенное вычисление*: когда условие истинно — вычисляется только `a`, а когда условие ложно —  вычисляется только `b` (налицо экономия времени).

Например:

```
>>> 'true' if True else 'false'
'true'
>>> 'true' if False else 'false'
'false'
```

Заметьте, что тернарный оператор — это *выражение* (expression), а не *инструкция* (statement). Это означает, что вы не можете использовать инструкции (вроде `pass`) или присваивания (`x = 5`, `x += 5`) внутри условного оператора:

```
>>> pass if False else pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pass if False else pass
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> # Python обрабатывает это как `x = (1 if False else y) = 2`
>>> # Часть `(1 if False else x)` верна, но
>>> # она не может быть слева от знака равенства.
>>> x = 1 if False else y = 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to conditional expression

>>> # То же, но со скобками...
>>> (x = 1) if False else (y = 2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (x = 1) if False else (y = 2)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(В версии 3.8 и выше "моржовый оператор" `:=` позволяет одновременно вычислить выражение, присвоить результат переменной, и вернуть это значение куда угодно, в том числе и в условие тернарного оператора. Но не стоит этим увлекаться — слишком быстро станет трудно разобраться в коде.)

Кроме того, поскольку это выражение, то часть `else` обязательна:

```
# Неверный синтаксис: мы не определили, какое будет значение, если
# условие окажется ложным.
a if True
```

Однако вы можете использовать тернарный оператор для присваивания значения переменной таким образом:

```
x = a if True else b
```

Или, например, в комбинации с оператором return:

```
def my_max(a, b):
    return a if a > b else b
```

О тернарном выражении следует думать как о "переключении" между двумя значениями. Его следует использовать, когда перед нами выбор одного из двух значений, а дальнейшие строки программы выполнятся вне зависимости от того, будет ли условие верно. Тернарный оператор используется, когда мы хотим вычислить выражение и потом что-то с ним сделать. В остальных случаях применяйте обычный `if`.

Имейте в виду, что некоторые питонисты недолюбливают тернарный оператор по следующим причинам:

- Порядок аргументов отличается от аналогичного классического тернарного оператора `condition ? a : b` многих других языков (например, C, C++, Go, Perl, Ruby, Java, JavaScript и т. д.). Это может привести к ошибкам, если человек незнаком с "необычным" поведением Питона в отношении тернарного оператора (он может перепутать порядок аргументов).
- Некоторые находят его неуклюжим, поскольку он идет вразрез с обычным ходом мысли (сначала об условии, а потом о действиях).
- Хотя "однострочный if" может быть очень полезен и делает код более лаконичным, он сильно его усложняет.

Если вам трудно запомнить порядок аргументов, то вспомните, что если произнести выражение с тернарным оператором вслух, получится примерно то же, что оператор и обозначает. Например, `x = 4 if b > 8 else 9` произносится как `x будет равно 4, если b больше чем 8, в противном случае 9`.

Официальная документация:

[Conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

[Is there an equivalent of C’s ”?:” ternary operator?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator)

Comment: Вы вроде как перевели ответ другого человека с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: @valixxx, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english

Comment: Перевод вопроса с ответом с английского языка эквивалентен публикации вопроса со своим ответом